# retrieve data from EventEmitter response -communication between 2 component Angular

Tags: angular, eventemitter

i have a EventEmitter in a child Component.ts

```
@Output()
 change: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
....
FormJson() {
  const myObjStr = JSON.stringify(this.address.value);
 this.change.emit(myObjStr);}
```

then in a parent component, the call of the event:

```
AddChange(event) {
this.addr = event;
console.log(this.addr);}
```

after the execution I have on the console this result :

```
home.component.ts:48 
{"items":[{"street":"df","city":"","state":"","Obligation":""}]}
Event {isTrusted: true, type: "change", target: input.validate.ng-untouched.ng-valid.ng-dirty, currentTarget: app-addresse, eventPhase: 3, …}
```

how can i only have not the other informations :

```
{"items":[{"street":"df","city":"","state":"","Obligation":""}]}
```

Comment: what is this.address.value referring to .?

Comment: The event emitter passes through whatever you told it to pass through. So you need to fix what you are emitting to only be the thing you want.

Comment: You should modify "this.address.values" so that it only passes what you need. Also you don't have to stringify the value, send an entire object.

Comment: @FranklinPious it refers to FormGroup that contain items Street, City, State and Obligation